# Suppress exceptions from multiple statements in Python with a single context manager?

Tags: python, exception

The `contextlib.supress()` function allows you to elegantly suppress an `Exception` without the verbosity of the `try...catch`. However, once an exception is thrown, the context manager closes. For instance, the following code:

```py
from contextlib import suppress

with suppress(Exception):
    print("a")
    raise Exception()
    print("b")
    raise Exception()
print("c")
```

Will print:

```
a
c
```

Is there a similar function, or suitable design pattern, which would allow processing to continue after an exception is raised, so the output would be as follows?

```
a
b
c
```

Comment: I don't think anything like this is possible. There's no way for any contruct to get back into the context where the exception was raised and continue past it.

Comment: I guess what you're looking for is something that makes `raise` just do nothing. That would require something built into the language.

Comment: Agreeing with everyone else.  This doesn't exist in Python.